# Alternative to inductor on IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, inductor, gyrator

I was running through the datasheet of [CC2500](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Fcc2500.pdf) `(Low-Cost Low-Power 2.4 GHz RF Transceiver)` which has a dimension of `2.40mm X 2.40mm` approx. It was really amazing to find such transceivers to be fabricated in such a small area.Infact a transceiver requires a lot of `R`,`C` and even `L`.Resistors, Capacitors and semiconductors are easy to be imagined on an IC but an Inductor!!!

I haven't work in any VLSI industry so it would be great if someone can tell how these inductor logic is implemented on IC. Although it is said that [gyrators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrator) are alternative solution, but thanks for pointing if my knowledge is correct.

Comment: Please make it a habit to include a link to the datasheet in your question. It may be helpful for users who want to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Steven, but question has no strong relation with datasheet, however I'll add it :)

Comment: I think the datasheet is relevant. Some devices have a lot of pins for external capacitors and/or resistors. This one seems to need only a couple of external parts. The datasheet also shows a block diagram. Thanks for updating the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inductors have been [fabricated on ICs](http://www-smirc.stanford.edu/papers/Orals98s-cpyue.pdf) for a long time now. The inductance can obviously not be that high, but there are various methods to compensate for this.

[image]
<sub>(source: [dow.com](http://www.dow.com/cyclotene/images/IC-Cu-Inductor.jpg))</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inductors in ICs are so commonplace that there is an industry and research branch for inductance calculation for that purpose.

A note on gyrators is that they can *act* like inductors I-V characteristic wise, but they cannot *store* energy. Also, they operate in MHz range in applications that I have seen, to replace very bulky inductors on the filters of those frequencies.

A gyrator would actively consume power, I think it would not resonate due to the fact that it cannot store energy.